# Gamma Function Integration Identity

Tags: gamma-function

I'm currently studying gamma function and its relation to factorials but I eventually encounter this problem that has something to do with integrals... Im good with differentiation but poor in integration,,can you give me a hint how to solve this one? Any idea would be of greta help thanks in advance!!

If $a>0, b>0,$ then $\int_{0}^{1}(1 - x)^{a-1}x^{b - 1}dx = \frac{\Gamma \left( a \right)\Gamma \left( b \right)}{\Gamma \left( a+b \right)}$

Comment: This may be of help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514025/relation-between-beta-and-gamma-distributions

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function