# Showing that $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y) = \Gamma(x+y)\int\limits_0^1 \lambda^{x-1}(1-\lambda)^{y-1}d\lambda$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function

On page 56 of Titchmarsh's Theory of Functions, Titchmarsh makes the following claim:

\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} &= \phi(x,y); (x>0,y>0)
\end{align}
where \begin{align}
\phi(x,y) &=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{v^{y-1}}{(1+v)^{x+y}}dv\\
&= 2 \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2x-1}(\sin\theta)^{2y-1}d\theta\\
&= \int\limits_0^1 \lambda^{x-1}(1-\lambda)^{y-1}d\lambda
\end{align}

I understand how the first integral is achieved using substitution, but I can't figure out how to go from the first integral to the second or the second integral to the third.

Comment: Search for the derivation of the relation between beta and gamma functions.

Comment: Second to third is by the substitution $\lambda = (\cos x)^{2}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514025/relation-between-beta-and-gamma-distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first to second,

\begin{align}
\phi(x,y) &=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{v^{y-1}}{(1+v)^{x+y}}dv\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{(\tan^2\theta)^{y-1}}{(1+(\tan^2\theta))^{x+y}}d(\tan^2\theta)\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\frac{(\tan^2\theta)^{y-1}}{(\sec^2\theta)^{x+y}}(2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta)d\theta\\
&=2\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}(\sin\theta)^{2y-2+1}(\cos \theta)^{-(2y-2+1)+(2x+2y)-2}d\theta\\
&= 2 \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2x-1}(\sin\theta)^{2y-1}d\theta\\
\end{align}

Now can you think of the next substitution? (Hint: look at the limits and the exponents)